# How can I perform automated tests against MS Word documents using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

We regularly need to perform a handful of relatively simple tests against a bunch of MS Word documents. As these checks are currently done manually, I am striving for a way to automate this. For example:

- Check if every page actually has a page number and verify that it is correct.
- Verify that a version identifier in the page header is identical across all pages.
- Check if the document has a table of contents.
- Check if the document has a table of figures.
- Check if every figure has a caption.

et cetera. Is this reasonably feasible using PowerShell in conjunction with a Word API?

Comment: Will your PS code be allowed to access the Word object model via automation/Interop, or are you trying to avoid that, e.g. so you can run server-side? Just IMO but you can make this as easy or as hard as you like. - e.g. “how close to the figure does. The caption have to be and do you identify it’s a caption by looking for one of the standard Word caption field numbering sequences, or what?

Comment: Yes, it can access the object model, client side run is sufficient. I want to keep it simple and I can develop "business rules" for that if necessary (e.g. all captions MUST be created using this or that Word mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

Powershell can access Word via its object model/Interop (on Windows, at any rate) and AIUI can also work with the Office Open XML OOXML) API, so really you should be able to write any checks you want on the document content. What is slightly less obvious is how you verify that the document content will result in a particular "printed appearance". I'm going to start with some comments on the details first.

Just bear in mind that in the following notes I'm just pointing out a few things that you *might have to* deal with. If you're examining documents produced by an organisation where people are already broadly speaking following the same standards, it may be easier.

Of the 5 examples you give, without checking the details I couldn't say *exactly* how you would do them, and there could be difficulties with all of them, but *for example*

```
Check if every page actually has a page number and verify that it is correct.
```

Difficult using either OOXML or the object model, because what you would really be checking is that the header for a particular section had a visible { PAGE } field code. Because that field code *might* be nested inside other fields that say "if  don't display this field code", it's not so easy to be sure that there would be a page number.

Which is what I mean by checking the document's "printed appearance" - if, for example, you can use the object model to print to PDF and have some mechanism that lets PS inspect the PDF's content, that might be a better approach.

```
Verify that a version identifier in the page header is identical across all pages.
```

Similar problem to the above, IMO. It depends partly on how the version identifier might be inserted. Is it just a piece of text? Could it be constructed from a number of fields? Might it reference Document Properties or Variables, or Custom XML content?

```
Check if the document has a table of contents.
```

Perhaps enough to look for a TOC field that *does not have* certain options, such as a \c option that a Table of Figures would contain.

```
 Check if the document has a table of figures.
```

Perhaps enough to check for a TOC field that *does have* a \c option, perhaps with a specific parameter such as "Figure"

```
 Check if every figure has a caption.
```

Not sure that you can tell whether a particular image is "a Figure". But if you mean "verify that every graphic object has a caption", you could probably iterate through the inline and floating graphics in the document and verify that there was something that looked like a Word standard caption paragraph within a certain distance of that object. Word has two standard field code patterns for captions AFAIK (one where the chapter number is included and one where it isn't), so you could look for those. You could measure a distance between the image and the caption by ensuring that they were no more than a predefined number of paragraphs apart, or in the case of a floating image, perhaps that the paragraph anchoring the image was no more than so many paragraphs away from the caption.

A couple of more general problems that you might have to deal with:
 - just because a document contains a certain feature, such as a ToC field, does not mean that it is visible. A TOC field might have been formatted as not visible. Even harder to detect, it could have been formatted as colored white.
 - change tracking. You *might* have to use the Word object model to "accept changes" before checking whether any given feature is actually there or not. Unless you can find existing code that would help you do that using the OOXML representation of the document, that's probably a strong case for doing checks via the object model.

Some final observations

- for future checks, perhaps worth noting that in principle you could create a "DocumentInspector" that users could call from Word BackStage to perform checks on a document. Not sure you can force users to run it, or that you could create it in PS, but perhaps a useful tool.
- longer term, if you are doing a very large number of checks, perhaps worth considering whether you could train a ML model to try to detect problems.